# How to correctly setup a path relative to running script also in tests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, relative-path, pytest

In order to set some paths to access subdirectories of my app (like `locale/`), I use this in a `settings.py`:

```
__process_name = os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])
__abspath = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])
__l1 = len(__process_name)
__l2 = len(__abspath)
rootdir = __abspath[:__l2-__l1]
```

And then, for instance to access `data/`:

```
datadir = rootdir + "data/"
```

Problem is, when I run this `settings.py` when I run the tests (e.g. `python3 -m py.test`), then `sys.argv[0]` doesn't match myapp anymore and the tests script can't access `data/`.

I wonder how to deal with this, for instance:

- Is there a way to get the same rootdir from both my app and the tests suite?
- Or, should I keep `settings.py` for my app only, and provide the tests suite with the correct (hardcoded) rootdir?
- Or define an `installdir` in a configuration file, that would be setup during installation and then used by both my app (instead of the snippet above) and its tests suite?
- I also thought about replacing `sys.argv[0]` by `'myappname'`, but, as there are different directories having the same name, it's not sure it gets the right one. (Plus, what if there is one installed version and one dev version at another place: how to make the distinction between them?)

So, what would be the best way to handle this?

Comment: Have you tried using `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))`?

Comment: @TheCompiler No, hadn't tried that. I will have to actually hack it a little bit to handle a directory's level difference, but that's definitely solving the case elegantly! This is clever! You can add this as the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the usual thing to do is `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))`.

`__file__` is the path to the current module, `os.path.abspath` makes sure it's absolute, and `os.path.dirname` gives you the directory part of it.

If you have a module as part of a package and need e.g. a directory in the package, you can either use `os.path.join(..., os.pardir)` as appropriate, or if possible import the package (i.e. its `__init__.py`) and do `your_package.__file__`.

An alternative you might want to consider as well is specifying your data as package data using setuptools, and then using the `pkg_resources` API to access it.